# How to show that $\frac{1}{\tan(x/2)}=2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sin(jx)$ in Cesàro way/sense?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Show that if $x \neq 0,\pm 2 \pi,\pm 4 \pi, \dots$, then

$$\frac{1}{\tan(x/2)}=2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sin(jx)$$

in Cesàro way/sense. Some hint whether to manipulate

$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sin(jx) \tag1$

into (using partial sum of ($1$)) 
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sin(jx)= \dots$

Comment: Would someone edit it better if I have lost some thing when I edited it lately. I don't know why it does not put $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j(x)$ after $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}sin(jx)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx) = \dfrac{\cos(x/2) - \cos((n+2)x/2)}{2\sin(x/2)}$$
To prove this multiply, $S_n(x)$ by $\sin(x/2)$ and make use of the fact that $$\sin(A) \sin(B) = \dfrac{\cos(A-B) - \cos(A+B)}2$$ and do telescopic cancellation.

**EDIT**
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} S_n(x)}N = \dfrac1{2 \tan(x/2)} - \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos((n+2)x/2)}{2N \sin(x/2)}$$

The second term without the $N$ in the denominator is bounded (Why? One way is to evaluate the sum in a similar spirt as above or write it as exponential and use geometric series to see that it is bounded when $x \neq k \pi$). Hence, if you take the limit as $N \to \infty$, the second term will tend to $0$.

Comment: But how would you use Cesàro method i.e. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} sin(jx) \rightarrow a$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$, where $a \in N$ with that proof? What is telescopic cancellation? I know that it is A-B+(B-C)+(C-D)=A-D, but hard time in figuring out how to implement it in this case?

Comment: @alvoutila What you want to show is the following. If $$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$$ then you want to look at $$S_N = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} s_n}N$$ and show that the limit of $S_N$ exists. (This is the Cesaro way.) I have added details to the post above and hope now it is clear.

Comment: If it suites you I come back to comment because I have to first set problem which I try to solve and then compare your ideas with what I have achieved. And maybe then I can formulate some questions for you to answer. I understood your comment above, because I know what is Cesàro way as presented in lectures. But Hint and Edit part are not yet fully understood.

Comment: firstly I think that you don't have to care constant 2 at all. I mean it is all about $\sum_{n=1}^{N}s_n$, where $s_n=sin(nx)$?